# In CSS how can I auto fill a container when the other element width is unknown?

Tags: css, width

I have two elements inside a containing element. The container is 960px widt with 10px of padding on each side. I have two floated elements that are next to one another. The first element will contain text of an unknown amount and the other element will need to adjust to fill the rest of the containers width.

For example:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="item1">Unknown size</div><div id="item2">fill in width of left over</div>
</div>
```

edit---->

more information:

my first element will contain an unknown amount of text. The second element will contain none but will rather contain a background and be treated more like an accent to the text. Think of it like this:

START YOUR ENGINES! (followed by a pattern of tire marks)
CAUTION ON THE TURN! (followed by a pattern of tire marks)

These two items have different lengths for text so the tire marks would be different too. but I need the all to be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can float `#item1` and not float `#item2` like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/CevQH/1/

because of the float, #item1 will be ontop of #item2, it is removed from the regular document flow. As you can see in the jsfiddle, the text in item2 flows next to item1 while the background takes up the entire width.

If you place items underneath it, you should add a `clear:left` to the first item after `#item2`

Comment: Keeping the background of #item2 separate from #item1 is the biggest issue.

Comment: just give item1 a background color and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure that one column will always have the greater height you can leave that column unfloated and absolutely position the second column. The second column would hold to the container (which would need `position: relative`) by the top and bottom.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.left {
  width: 200px;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Fiddled here: http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/5mRDM/

Comment: the size of each "column" will always be unknown in this case.

Comment: you may want to check out [this example](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm). It uses some trickery to get two columns to appear but the backgrounds aren't necessarily part of the columns. What's actually happening is there are two containers with clear fixes to surround the columns. 

Not sure if that helps, probably depends on the visual design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox.Chris explained very well [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)